# Как при авторизации профиля менять элементы меню шапки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, авторизация

**С помощью базы данных на firebase создала авторизацию .Как при входе или выходе из аккаунта менять элементы меню? Надо чтобы стандартно стояло Вход и Регистрация ,при входе в аккаунт менялось на Личный кабинет и Выйти .Делаю с помощью hide и js,но все эти элементы меню пропадают**

```js
  const txtLogin = document.getElementById("txtLogin");
  const txtPass = document.getElementById("txtPassword");
  const txtValidPass = document.getElementById("txtValidPassword");
  const btnReg = document.getElementById("btnReg");
  const headauth = document.getElementById("headauth");
  const headprofile = document.getElementById("headprof");
  
  ;
  

  btnReg.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const Login = txtLogin.value;
    const Pass = txtPass.value;
    const ValidPass = txtValidPass.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    if (Pass === ValidPass) {
      const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Login, Pass);
      promise.catch((event) => alert(event.message));
    } else {
      alert("Пароли не совпадают");
    }
  });
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
   
    if (firebaseUser) {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      alert("Вы  вошли в аккаунт");
      headprofile.classList.add('hide') ;         
    } else {
      alert("Вы не вошли в аккаунт");
      headauth.classList.add('hide') ; 

    }
  });
}();
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
} 
.hide2{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;469;500;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/authorization.css" />


  <title>GameLand.by</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="sticky-top">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center ">
          <svg width="35px" height="35px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-controller contriller mb-1 "
            fill="currentColor" style="color:#63ADD0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M11.119 2.693c.904.19 1.75.495 2.235.98.407.408.779 1.05 1.094 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.815-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773a11.307 11.307 0 0 1-.739-.809c-.126-.147-.25-.291-.368-.422-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.422-.243.283-.494.576-.739.81-.398.378-.877.705-1.513.772a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772.486-.485 1.331-.79 2.235-.98.932-.196 2.03-.292 3.119-.292 1.089 0 2.187.096 3.119.292zm-6.032.979c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.505C4.861 9.97 5.978 9.026 8 9.026s3.139.943 3.965 1.855c.164.182.307.35.44.505.214.25.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z" />
            <path
              d="M11.5 6.026a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm2 0a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-7-2.5h1v3h-1v-3z" />
            <path
              d="M3.5 6.526h3v1h-3v-1zM3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .258.966l-1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1-.612-.354zm9.976 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.353-.613l-1.932-.518a.5.5 0 1 0-.259.966l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 0 .612-.354z" />
          </svg>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">
            <h4>GameLand</h4>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 text-center ">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav col-6 mr-auto text-center">
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">Новости</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Игры</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Календарь</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="contacts.html">Контакты</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav col-6 mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 hide" id="headauth">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="authorization.html">Вход</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 hide" id="headauth">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold " href="registration.html">Регистрация</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 hide2" id="headprof">
             <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Выйти</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 hide2" id="headprof">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold " href="#">Личный кабинет</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <div class="container h-100">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                    <div class="searchbar">
                      <input class="search_input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
                      <a href="#" class="search_icon">
                        <svg width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search  search  mt-2 mr-2   "
                          fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />

                          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        </i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-auth.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a38862ad2c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/registrationforms.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для конкретного решения:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.navbar-nav')
const controlButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.headauth'), ...document.querySelectorAll('.headprof')]
// авторизация или регистрация
// ...

let isAuth = false

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  menu.classList.toggle('hide')
  for (let i = 0; i < controlButtons.length; i++) {
    controlButtons[i].classList.toggle('hide')
  }
  isAuth = !isAuth
  if (isAuth) {
    this.innerHTML = 'Выйти'
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Войти'
  }
  
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9 text-center ">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav col-6 mr-auto text-center hide">
      <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
        <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">Новости</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Игры</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
        <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Календарь</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
        <a class="nav-link " href="contacts.html">Контакты</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav col-6 mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headauth">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="authorization.html">Вход</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headauth">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold " href="registration.html">Регистрация</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headprof hide">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Выйти</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headprof hide">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold " href="#">Личный кабинет</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
        <div class="container h-100">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="searchbar">
              <input class="search_input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
              <a href="#" class="search_icon">
                <svg width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search  search  mt-2 mr-2   " fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />

                          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                        </svg>
                </i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Войти</button>
```

Убрал `id="headprof"` и `id="headauth"`, но добавил их в классы

`<li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headauth">`,
`<li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2 headprof hide">`.

Не давайте, пожалуйста, **одинаковые id** разным элементам, используйте для этого классы.